# Go: /usr/local/go/bin does not exist on CentOS 7.9

Tags: linux, go, centos7

I'm on a CentOS 7.9 virtual machine and I'm trying to install Go following this procedure (rif. https://computingforgeeks.com/install-go-golang-on-centos-rhel-linux/)

`sudo yum -y install wget`

`wget https://go.dev/dl/go1.19.3.src.tar.gz`

`sha256sum go1.19.3.src.tar.gz`

`sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go*.src.tar.gz`

Then I've added

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`

in

- $HOME/.profile
- /etc/profile

and finally

`source $HOME/.profile`

`source /etc/profile`

But when I try the command

`go version`

the result is

`-bash: go: command not found`

I've seen that no `bin` directory is under `/usr/local/go` path as shown in the picture

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are downloading the source, not the binary.  You should be doing

```
wget https://go.dev/dl/go1.19.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

not

```
wget https://go.dev/dl/go1.19.3.src.tar.gz
```